# INSERT VALUES into empty column

Tags: mysql

```
 $querychange = 
  mysql_query("UPDATE table SET clounm='$newvale' WHERE email='$email'")
```

but put $newvalue into the nearest empty cell

Comment: How is the specific table row specified? For the `null` check, you can use `where yourColumn is null`.

Comment: Post some sample data eith expected result

Comment: Also note that you can only update a column of existing row

Comment: I could make it null, then what would the mysql code be?

Comment: What would be the use case for this?

Comment: user1557whatever, if your table design resembles excel sheet - then your table design is wrong. use table (x int, y int, value int) and transform to excel-like-table on demand...

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `col_name` = `col_value` WHERE `record_name` = 'ID'
```

for example

```
UPDATE `student` SET `marks` = 50 WHERE `name` = 'Jack'
```

This will set all records with name Jack to 50 marks.

Comment: yes but in the code there is a session variable which =$email so only that row can be changed

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for

```
UPDATE table SET clounm='$newvale' WHERE email IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

Comment: that sounds like what I'm looking for I'll try it out, TVM for the post.